# Authorize payment, collect after

Tags: cognito-forms

We are looking to use Cognito Forms for online sales, however, instead of collecting the money through Stripe immediately we would like to authorize the payment using Stripe when they submit the form and then collect later when the order is confirmed in-house. I know Stripe offers this option independently (https://stripe.com/blog/auth-capture), and also when it's integrated with JotForms (https://www.jotform.com/help/292-How-to-Enable-Payment-Authorization).

Am a correct that Cognito Forms does not currently have this capability?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; Cognito Forms does not currently offer the ability to perform two-step payments with Stripe.